Jira Python get description from SUB-Task
I am trying to get the description from a subtask in Jira. I am able to get all the information from the main task: summary, status, description, subtasks, etc... but when I pull data for a specific subtask, I am missing the description field.
ticket_data = jira.issue("PROJ-12345")
for subtask in ticket_data.fields.subtasks:
    if "generate data" in (subtask.fields.summary).lower():
        st_desc = subtask.fields.description      # ERROR
        print(subtask.raw['fields']               # Description is not a field

I thought that maybe I should try to pull only the subtask; it makes sense to me that the main task would have limited information regarding its subtasks. But when I pull the data for the subtask directly, I get the same exact information as from the main task and the description field is missing. I even tried to define that I wanted ONLY the description field.
subtask_data = jira.issue(subtask_key, fields='description')
print(subtask_data.raw['fields'])       # Returns same data - Description is not a field

I am able to create subtasks with the description without issue.
name: "subtask_1"
project: "PROJ"
summary: "Generate data for the given task"
assignee: "myself@email.com"
description: "All the data I need for the description entered here"
issuetype: "Sub-task"
parent: "PROJ-12345"

I have found several posts related to getting data from subtasks or how to create subtasks, I have even found a post on Atlassian where it appears to be a similar issue, but it's unanswered. So I thought I would ask the brilliant users of Stack Overflow for some help. :) What am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

In a previous edit of your own answer to the question, you showed the data of the subtasks list:
'subtasks': [
    {
        'id': '12345678', 
        'key': 'PROJ-555', 
        'self': 'https://jira.myurl.com/issue/12345678', 
        'fields': {
            'summary': 'Generate data for the given task', 
            'status': {}, 
            'priority': {}, 
            'issuetype': {}
        }
    }
]

You had tried to access the dictionary data at subtask.fields.key (with subtask being an element of the list), but fields and key are actually on the same "level" in the subtask dictionary.
key is not part of the nested dictionary fields, but rather part of the subtask dictionary.
Your only error was in the hierarchy of the nested dictionaries.
I usually try to avoid such error by first printing the full object/list/dict once, and then homing in on the actual data I need to extract for my use case. Doing that step by step, prevents errors such as this one.

Yep. Silly mistake, but you were able to catch it. I could have also used the element and converted to a string, but this method is probably the most accurate. Thank you!

I think your approach to call jira.issue(subtask_key) is correct, but I noticed a typo:
subtask_data = jira.issue(subtask_key, fields='description')

Good catch. That is not in the actual code; it was just a typo on this page. I have fixed it on this page, but if that was a typo in the code I can definitely see that causing issues.
As of now, it looks like description is not returned whether I define the fields or not.

I figured out what I was doing wrong.
Previously, I was trying to get the data through a loop
ticket_data = jira.issue("PROJ-12345")
for subtask in ticket_data.fields.subtasks:
    # print (subtask.fields.key)  # !Error
    if "generate data" in (subtask.fields.summary).lower():
        # print(subtask)                          # Prints "PROJ-555"
        subtask_data = jira.issue(subtask)
        print(subtask_data.raw['fields'])       # Description is not a field

But, as described in the question, it returned minimal data and description was not a field.
I tried to get the key from the subtasks field in the main task, but was incorrectly using subtask.fields.key rather than just subtask.key. Using this field allowed for me to pull the data which included the much needed "description" field.
ticket_data = jira.issue("PROJ-12345")
for subtask in ticket_data.fields.subtasks:
    if "generate data" in (subtask.fields.summary).lower():
        subtask_data = jira.issue(subtask.key)
        print(subtask_data.raw['fields'])       # Description IS a field! Woot woot!

Alternatively, I could have also converted the subtask object to a string like so: subtask_data = jira.issue(str(subtask))

Is subtask.fields.key another typo (in your text, just before the second code block)? Because I can see why that wouldn't work: key and fields are actually on the same level, not key "below" fields ...

@Guillius No, it's not a typo. What I was showing is the raw data (subtask.raw['fields']) and should not be confused with how you actually call for the data in the fields (subtask.fields.key). If I were to get something in the fields section shown above, I believe I would query subtask.fields.fields.summary. But IDK, for sure because I've never tried that. I'll give it a shot, along with querying the key without fields and let you know how it goes.

@Guillius it appears that I was wrong. subtask.key does indeed work! I completely overlooked that. So, converting to string, or using the .key works. I am updating the answer to reflect this. If you would like to submit an answer showing this, I will mark it correct.
